# How to show inline help using simple css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am designing a page with multiple help link. All link help will appear at the same location. Clicking on help link I want to display css popup

example I have two help context on the page with div tag

< div class="inlineExplaination" id="div1" >

```
<a href="#">Help 1</a>

<div class="content">

    <h3>This is title</h3>
    <div class="block">
        <h4>What is this4>
        <p>This is... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

< div class="inlineExplaination" id="Div1" >

```
< a href="#"Help 2</a>

<div class="content">
    <h3>
        This is title</h3>
    <div class="block">
        <h4>What is that?</h4>
        <p>That is... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

my jquery looks like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inlineExplaination").click(function () {
        var popID = $(this).attr('id'); 

        //Hide previous dialog
        $(".content").hide();

        //show the one which user clicked
        $('#' + popID).click(function () {
            $(this).children("div.content").addClass("active");
        });
    });

});
```

I click on the link on the page to show help nothing happens. I think the issue is that onclick I am hiding all content class and then I am trying to make the one which is clicked by user active. in this case it doesn't show anything when I click on "Help " link. I am able to make it work as desired but I amd getting inconsistent behavior.

This is my first post and first time jquery so pelase bear with me. One constrainnt I have is that cannot access any internet site which means I cannot access google jquery UI classes.

Thanks
Miracles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need another `.click()`

```
 $(".inlineExplaination").click(function() {
    var popID = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".content").removeClass('active');
    $(this)
        .find("div.content")
        .addClass("active");

});
```

Here's a working fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/yFEmD/

---

If you want to hide currently open block by clicking on a link inside, you can attach separate handler. Notice, that in your code "opening" event is attached to parent block, so clicking on a link will also trigger `.click()` event for it. This means that it will be hidden and instantly shown. To avoid that you need to add `.stopPropagation()` call.

Here's a fiddle that illustrates that: http://jsfiddle.net/nev3rm0re/yFEmD/2/

Comment: Thanks German, it worked. The reason I want another click is to able to close when user clicks on the title. That brings another question, how can add "X" on the pupup and clicking on that closes the dialog?